# Is there evidence of effects of votes of no confidence on enrollment?

Tags: administration, governance

Is there any evidence that a successful vote of no confidence on the president of a small college will have a negative impact on enrollment?  This warning is being used by the administration of my college to encourage faculty not to vote *no confidence.*

Comment: Related: [What are the repercussions of a "vote of no confidence" made by faculty?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28016/what-are-the-repercussions-of-a-vote-of-no-confidence-made-by-faculty)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is opinion unsupported by evidence, but I think it's right. {grin}

If your student population is drawn primarily from the local area, then the publicity might dissuade a few potential students from applying.  If the student population is drawn from a wide area (nationally or international) then most potential students will never know about the vote of no confidence, no matter how it turns out.